# How to solve these simultaneous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following equations for $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$

$$ K_0\, x_1(t) + K_1\, \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}  +  M_0\, \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt} + x_3(t) =A_0\,\sin (\alpha_0 t) \tag{1} $$

$$ M_0\, \frac{dx_1(t)}{dt} + L_0\,x_2(t) + K_1\, \frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}+L_1\,\int x_2(t)\, dt  =0 \tag{2} $$

$$ x_1(t) -\alpha_1\,B_1\,\cos(\alpha_1\,t + \phi) \, x_3(t)- \big[B_0+B_1\,\sin(\alpha_1\,t + \phi) \big] \frac{dx_3(t)}{dt}   =0 \tag{3} $$

**Here is my try** using Laplace transform:

I can assume $x_1(0)=0$, and define $x_2(0)=x_{20}$, and $x_3(0)=x_{30}$

$$(1) \Rightarrow K_0\, X_1(s) + K_1\, sX_1(s)+  M_0\, sX_2(s)+ X_3(s) + M_0\, x_{20} =  \frac{A_0\alpha_0}{s^2+\alpha_0^2} \tag{4} $$

$$(2) \Rightarrow  M_0\, X_1(s) + L_0\, X_2(s) +K_1\, sX_2(s)+  L_1\, \frac{X_2(s)}{s}+ X_3(s)+ K_1\, x_{20} =0 \tag{5} $$
 <s>Next step brings me the trouble. I cannot simply take the Laplace transform of (3)</s>

**Update 1** (as suggested by @Cesareo)

Using the Euler's expansion of sine and cosine (3) can be transformed to

$$ X_1(s) - B_0 s X_3(s) -\\ 
\frac{B_1  (\alpha_1 +1) s}{2} \big(e^{i \phi} X_3(s-i \alpha_1) + e^{-i \phi}  X_3(s+i \alpha_1)\big)+x_{30} (B_0 - B_1 \sin \phi)=0 \tag{6}$$

**Now, my question is:**
 How can I move forward from here? How can I handle $X_3(s \pm i \alpha_1)$ ifI want to solve for $X_3(s)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

$$
\mathcal{L}(\cos(\alpha t)x(t)) = \mathcal{L}(\frac 12(e^{i\alpha t}+e^{-i\alpha t})x(t))
$$

and

$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{i\alpha t}x(t)e^{-s}dt = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-(s-i\alpha)t}x(t) dt = X(s-i\alpha)
$$

so after the Laplace transformation you should handle a system of difference equations ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try it and update here. isn't $\mathcal{L} \big(e^{i \alpha t} x(t) \big) = X(s-i \alpha) $?

Comment: @Pojj  You are right. I had a little imagination left.

Comment: any suggestion how I can move forward from here? (Edited the question)

Comment: @Pojj In the same line, eliminating $X_1(s), X_2(s)$ we arrive to a quasi polynomial equation for $X_3(s)$ with the structure
$$
f_1(s)X_3(s)+f_2(s)\left(e^{i\phi}X_3(s-i\alpha_1)+e^{-i\phi}X_3(s+i\alpha_1)\right)= C_0
$$
with $f_1(s),f_2(s)$ polynomial fractions ...